# If Then Else not working and I dunno why?

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably stupid and Im not seeing it. I have a simple sub 'Field Sheets' run when my field tech clicks a 'Field View' button so they only see the named sheets (code-named) they are interested in. The view should always be centered on codename 'Dashboard Sheet' after a view-change button (hence the actsh.Activate)

Currently I check all worksheets and if they aren't one of the defined 'field view' sheets, they are set to hidden. Im also setting the ones that ARE defined to visible ('Field View' should be these four sheets and nothing else). I'm getting an 'Else without if' compile error at the top of this. This only broke when I realized clicking 'Field View' (which runs 'Field_Sheets') didn't pull up sheets like codename 'MonitoringSheet' unless they were always visible and added the 'else'. I want to set a few buttons to pull up specific named sheets in the view and hide all others. Im using codenames for sheets internally because these go to a bunch of managers who love to rename their sheets so they feel like they've contributed. Somebody smack me with what Im not seeing?

```
Sub Field_Sheets()

Dim wsheet As Worksheet
Dim actsh As Worksheet

Set actsh = DashboardSheet
For Each wsheet In Worksheets
    
    If wsheet.CodeName <> "DashboardSheet" And _
        wsheet.CodeName <> "FieldEntrySheet" And _
        wsheet.CodeName <> "SystemDataSheet" And _
        wsheet.CodeName <> "MonitoringSheet" _
    Then wsheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    
    Else
    wsheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If
    
Next wsheet

actsh.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Move `wsheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden` to a new line.

Comment: you have a single line `If .. then` statement, which is interepretted as being implicitly closed by the compiler. If you need to use an else clause, you have two options: either add the else clause onto the end of your `then` clause, or move the contents of the `then` clause to a new line (as big ben has suggested)